# Get the last entryset of the map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need to get the last entry set of the map.
But my map has this parameter:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Object>>> map = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,Object>>>();
```

Given a example below:
If I have a map with this kind of value:

```
{1=  
   ANIMALS=
    {1=
        {1=
            {field1=dog,field2=cat}, 
            1=
                {1=
                    {1=
                        {field1=bird,field2=horse}}, 
                2=
                    {1=
                        {field1=snake,field2=cow}}}}
```

I'm thinking to use `instanceOf` but i am not familiar with that.
Every map can contain another map. That's why i used `Object`.

**how can i get the last entryset of the `Object`?**
my output should be:

```
{1=
   {field1=dog,field2=cat}, 
{2=
   {field1=bird,field2=horse},
{3=
   {field1=snake,field2=cow}
```

the last map will be

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This is frightening. What on earth do you need this for?

Comment: Perhaps you should begin by using `List` for the `Integer->???` maps?

Comment: @Dave - My word! \*loses monocle in teacup\*

Comment: I must agree with the previous commenters, perhaps you should rethink your design of this program.

Comment: Use another data structure better suited for your problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "last"?  HashMaps have no concept of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use recursive datastructure then you need recursive algorithm.

Do a simple recursive function and once type for map.get(key) is not a hashmap you know that you reach bottom of the tree.

But, as somebody said (Knuth?) - don't design algorithms, design datastructures. For you it looks like that tree modification could do a job. Then you can apply bread-first search and find all leaf nodes. In fact, this hashmap of hashmaps of hashmaps is actually a tree, but because you don't use any interface above HashMap/Value you forced to use cast on Object(it still Okay, it just not 'right' OOP way to do things).

You can find a lot of sample tree structures/algorithms (even in java) on wikipedia by yourself, so I'm not inserting links here.

Please let me know if you need any help with initial code.

Cheers

Comment: Hi,yes i did recursive method to fetch the object and also I modified my datastructure. Thanks guys..:D